# I use the driver <com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver>, but 'junit test' keep causing error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, junit

> version
>
> > mysql 8.0.18
> >
> > java 1.8
> >
> > spring 5.2.1.RELEASE
> >
> > junit 4.12

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hj</groupId>
    <artifactId>groupboard</artifactId>
    <name>groupboard</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>5.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.9.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- mybatis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

/groupboard/src/test/java/com.hj.groupboard.MySQLConnectionTest

```java
package com.hj.groupboard;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class MySQLConnectionTest {

    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/againdb?serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static final String USER = "admin";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "************";

    @Test
    public void testConnection() throws Exception {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD)) {
            System.out.println(connection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my console image of junit. please click this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkTLI.png).

I think this log from 'junit'.

> Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

and I think this log from 'java console log'.

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@4516af24

I think "java" has not returned error, but "junit" has returned error.

How do I fix that "junit" error or something.

[Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkTLI.png)

============================append======================================

Please find this picture of IDE image.

[IDE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr7Jn.png)

This error cause on `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");`, I think this means MySQLConnectionTest.java class dosent'n have a error, but maybe some library has a error.

Now I want to find how to fix or change the library.

And many thanks about everyone's help of this fix.
if I find solve this probleam, then I update this article.

Comment: And the question is...? Is the text under *console* an error or a warning? Does your code work? Consider removing `Class.forName(DRIVER);`...

Comment: The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. Have you tried to replace the driver class?

Comment: @deHaar I had removing `Class.forName(DRIVER);` but noting happened.

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí How can I replace the driver class? I was `private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";` to `private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";` but error dosent fix.

Comment: @Ppojin Could you add your pom.xml? Maybe, you do not have mysql-connector?

Comment: @Hatice I already put a "mysql-connector-java 8.0.18". May I need some put or replace something other libraries?

Comment: So I tried your code as is, and it worked just fine. Maybe the problem is in how you are executing your tests? Because connection wise everything works.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project?

Comment: @Hatice I think that project is auto rebuild.
but, just in case, I double checked, but the results did not changed.

Comment: @AlainCruz I executing using "run as junit", that's installed using maven, on eclipse. neither does not work that using intellij function.

Comment: @Ppojin I posted the code I am using to run the tests. I have never used the Maven to run my tests, so I am not sure about the configuration, but manually running the tests seems to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue resides on your maven's plugin configuration. I ran the test manually, with the following code and everything seems to work. Nonetheless, the driver warning shouldn't cause any error.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.run(MySQLConnectionTest.class);
    }
}
```

I am running this class inside the test folder, using the following directory structure.

```
src/
   test/
       java/
           Main.java
           MySQLConnectionTest.java
```

Comment: many thanks about your help. I append and run your class, but noting changed... ;~) ... I think this problem is "junit.Test" or some library has not support the version of MySQL 5.x or higher. But testing just fine. So I put off this fix.Thank you about your help

Answer (score 0):

That error causing by `log4jdbc`, that is logger library.

`log4jdbc v1.12` is using `'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'`, not `'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'`.

https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc/pull/88/commits/287f55a8a839a42e95e20788d80d29f2d995b6a1

But `'log4jdbc'` library dose not updated, since 2013, And that dose not fixed that issue.

In conclusion, `'log4jdbc'` cannot using with `MySQL 5.x or later`.

So I think I need to find something another logger library.